# how to pass parameters to asp.net web api get method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Following is my get method in ASP.NET Web API.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetDetails([FromBody] RetrieveDetails  eDetails)
{}
```

following is the class

```
public class RetrieveDetails
{ 
    public string name{ get; set; }     
    public string Type { get; set; } 
}
```

When I try to call `GetDetails` from Fiddler `eDetails` is always null.

http://localhost:101222/api/emailservice/GetDetails?name=testname&Type=testtype

I tried different methods but the value is always null.
If I change [HttpGet] to [HttpPost] and add the request body its working fine. But I need get method.

Comment: Change `[FromBody]` to `[FromUri]` and your url should work.

Comment: I changed it to [FromUri] , its working.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need [FromBody] there if you are passing values in URL for GET. You should be using [FromUri] if you are passing values in querystring.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api