# How can I pass object param to get method in web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I pass object parameter to get method? I searched a lot ,
for example [how to pass parameters to asp.net web api get method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766147/how-to-pass-parameters-to-asp-net-web-api-get-method)

Here It is mentioned that we should use [FromUri] but I could not see [FromUri] in .NET Core 2

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetDetails([FromUri] RetrieveDetails  eDetails)
{}
```

following is the class

```
public class RetrieveDetails
{ 
    public string Name{ get; set; }     
    public string Type { get; set; } 
    public List<MoreDetails> MoreDetails { get; set; }
} 

public class MoreDetails  { 
  public string DetailName{ get; set; } 
}
```

But FromUri can not be used in .NET Core 2

Comment: I can only think on JSON stringify and add the resulting string as query param.

Comment: nothing works ; I already have tried

Comment: Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: Specifically you are looking for `[FromQuery]`

Comment: It ıs not possible to pass complex type as get method, so I decided to define post method, It looks more proper

Comment: Sure it's the right way.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, we use `POST` method to pass an complex type.But you could also do it using `[FromQuery]` for `GET` method.

Action:

```
[HttpGet("Test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails([FromQuery]RetrieveDetails eDetails)
```

Url:

```
.../Test?eDetails.Name=hello&eDetails.Type=world&eDetails.MoreDetails[0].DetailName=size&eDetails.MoreDetails[1].DetailName=price
```